# Zend framework in ubuntu

Tags: zend-framework

My project name is 'zftutorial'

I can access 'localhost/zftutorial/public/' but
I can't access 'localhost/zftutorial/public/index/index' and other actions

What should i do?

Comment: Is there a specific error message? Are you using Apache? You may just need to enable mod_rewrite. (`$ sudo a2enmod rewrite`)

Comment: My server is LAMPP and my os is Ubuntu 13.4